# Python create list of dictionaries from csv on S3

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to take a CSV and create a list of dictionaries in python with the CSV coming from S3. Code is as follows:

```
import os
import boto3
import csv
import json
from io import StringIO
import logging
import time

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
s3Client = boto3.client('s3','us-east-1')

bucket = 'some-bucket'
key = 'some-key'

obj = s3Client.get_object(Bucket = bucket, Key = key)
lines = obj['Body'].read().decode('utf-8').splitlines(True)

newl = []

for line in csv.reader(lines, quotechar='"', delimiter=',',quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL,skipinitialspace=True, escapechar="\\"):
    newl.append(line)

fieldnames = newl[0]
newl1 = newl[1:]

reader = csv.DictReader(newl1,fieldnames)
out = json.dumps([row for row in reader])
jlist1 = json.loads(out)
```

but this gives me the error:

```
iterator should return strings, not list (did you open the file in text mode?)
```

if I alter the for loop to this:

```
for line in csv.reader(lines, quotechar='"', delimiter=',',quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL,skipinitialspace=True, escapechar="\\"):
    newl.append(','.join(line))
```

then it works, however there are some fields that have commas in them so this completely screws up the schema and shifts the data. For example:

```
|address1   |address2  |state|
------------------------------
|123 Main st|APT 3, Fl1|TX   |
```

becomes:

```
|address1   |address2  |state|null|
-----------------------------------
|123 Main st|APT 3     |Fl1  |TX  |
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You are using `quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL`, so are all fields actually double quoted in CSV? Can you try using a simple dialect like `excel` or `unix`?

Also, you have defined `escapechar`, but `doublequote` is set to true by default. Could any of these settings conflict with reading the CSV?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up changing the code to this:

```
obj = s3Client.get_object(Bucket = bucket, Key = key)
lines1 = obj['Body'].read().decode('utf-8').split('\n')
fieldnames = lines1[0].replace('"','').split(',')
testls = [row for row in csv.DictReader(lines1[1:], fieldnames)]
out = json.dumps([row for row in testls])
jlist1 = json.loads(out)
```

And got the desired result

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are building a list of lists here :

```
 newl.append(line)
```

and as the error says : iterator should return strings, not list

so try to cast line as a string:

```
newl.append(str(line))
```

Hope this helps :)